# ¿Por qué /^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$/ no coincide con una IP?

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Por qué al tener este código que valida una IP:

```js
var r = /^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$/;
var c = "192.168.0.1";
var d = r.test(c)
console.log(d);
```

NO funciona usando `^` al principio y `$` al final,

**Pero**, si uso `\b`…`\b` , **sí funciona**?

```js
var b = /\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b/;

var c = "192.168.0.1";

var d = b.test(c);

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**¿Por qué no coincide con `^` y `$`?**

Porque hay 3 grupos de números en tu regex, y son 4 números en una IP.

> <sup>Esto ya lo había respondido [Roberto León Oramas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/34391/roberto-le%C3%B3n-oramas) pero lo eliminó.</sup>

Y ojo, hay que escapar los puntos para que coincidan con un punto literal (y no con cualquier caracter.

Funciona con 4 números:

```js
var r = /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/;
var c = "192.168.0.1";
var d = r.test(c);
console.log(d);
```

O quizás quieras escribirla más corta:

```
/^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$/
```

- `(?:`…`){3}` es un grupo que repite al subpatrón `\.\d{1,3}` 3 veces.

**¿Por qué coincidía con `\b` si estaba mal?**

Porque coincidía con los 3 números, y luego `\b` encontraba un [límite de palabra completa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) entre el dígito (que es un caracter de palabra, o `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`) y el punto (que no es un caracter de palabra).

Es decir, coincidía sólo con una parte de la IP (la parte subrayada):

```
192.168.0.1
^^^^^^^^^
```

Podemos hacer que devuelva la coincidencia con [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) para cerciorarnos.

```js
var regex = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/; //3 números en vez de 4

var texto = "192.168.0.1";
var resultado = texto.match(regex);

console.log(resultado);
```